# How can I extract an ID from an URL in controller method in c#?

Tags: c#, url, model-view-controller, controller, anchor

I have a url with tab ID:

http://localhost:19269/Member/Edit/35b46e40-b4b4-4e61-bcee-f5cc4f4fac94#tab_content2

When I submit the  beginform I want to extract (in my controller) "#tab_content2" from the url.

I tried with "Request.Url.AbsolutePath" but I can only access http://localhost:19269/Member/Edit/35b46e40-b4b4-4e61-bcee-f5cc4f4fac94 and not the anchor link...

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't work because "Request.Url.AbsolutePath"  is only returning http://localhost:19269/Member/Edit/35b46e40-b4b4-4e61-bcee-f5cc4f4fac94

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: You can't

Browsers never transmit the hash part of the URI (anything after the `#` symbol).

[From RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4):

> When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from the URI by a crosshatch ("#") character, consists of additional reference information to be interpreted by the user agent after the retrieval action has been successfully completed. As such, it is not part of a URI, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.

The only way to obtain the *fragment* part is to use javascript to acquire it and then send it as a query string parameter or as post data inside forms.

A possible workaround (if you are using jQuery):

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
    $("#myHiddenInput").val(window.location.hash);
});
```

Assuming `myForm` as the id of your HTML form, and `myHiddenInput` as the id of an `<input type="hidden">` for this specific purpose.

From server side you have to map the hidden input to your model to be able to retrieve this data.

Comment: Don't know if it is the correct way but it worked! Little correction:

Comment: $("#myForm").submit(function() {
    $("#myHiddenInput").val(window.location.hash).toString();
});